# LogicApps editor and Visual Studio 2019 how?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, visual-studio-2019

With Vs2017 and LogicApp tools I was able to see my logic apps locally in design view within visual studio. I use Vs2019 and I don't have the option "open in visual Studio" any more, only option available from the cloud explorer is open in the portal.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its missing for me as well. I even went a step ahead and [downloaded](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VinaySinghMSFT.AzureLogicAppsToolsForVS2019) the `Azure Logic Apps Tools for Visual Studio 2019` which has only **`74 installs`** at the moment and i still can't see **Open in Visual Studio Designer**

[image: Extension Installed]

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with VS 2019 Enterprise.

I saw that it was missing the extension "Azure Logic Apps Tools For Visual Studio 2019". Ideally it should have come with Azure Development workload.

I installed that extension and it worked for me.

Thanks!

[Visual Studio 2019 Logic Apps Tools Extension Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTMAZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2019 just went GA yesterday, 02 APR 19.

It can take all of the SDKs some time to catch up.

In the mean time, Visual Studio 2017 is still fully supported and can be run side by side Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 0):

you could find the description in the official doc: [Quickstart: Create automated tasks, processes, and workflows with Azure Logic Apps - Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-logic-apps-with-visual-studio).

In there you could get the newest extension for VS 2019, and you could see an Important note with blue background:

> For Visual Studio 2019, Cloud Explorer can open the Logic App Designer
>   in the Azure portal, but can't yet open the embedded Logic App
>   Designer.

Due to the function development is not yet perfect, so for now you could only create new logic app and the Logic Apps in Azure cannot be opened.